# Is "a probability of needing..." grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

> There is a high probability that my car will need to be repaired.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above I created such that it does not use "that-clause". My example is as follows:

> There is a high probability of my car needing to be repaired.

I know that the word "probability" can have two forms: "probability that" and "probability of".  However, I could not find such usage as "a probability of needing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say either of these:

> There's a high probability my car is going to need to be repaired.

or

> There's a high probability my car is going to need repairs.